# Writing in text files using python does not work

Tags: python

When i create and write in a text file using the python code below, it executes successfully. However, when i open the text file, it does not show anything written in it!

```
newl=[]
    print ""
    while 1:
        tks=raw_input("# ")
        if tks=="/":
            text=''.join(newl)
            print text
            filen=open('c:/Users/Admin/Desktop/snickcode.txt', 'w')
            filen.write(str(text))
            filen.close
            print "#saved to desktop, please rename the file before reuse"
            print "{non}"
            print ""
            break
        else:
            gig=(str(tks))
            newl.append(gig)
            print newl
```

Comment: You already have `print text` before the file is written. Does it display anything?  Also, if nothing is written to the file, how can you say `"it executes successfully"`? Sounds like it's broken to me!

Comment: You only write to the file if the input is '/'. And you are just writing an empty string. If your input is different it will only append to the list but will not write to the file.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `/` is the first input you tried.
Because this

```
text=''.join(newl)
...
filen.write(str(text))
```

is what you write you the file and

```
newl=[]
```

doesn't contain any items at that point, the contents of the file remain 'empty'.